# getting string output of 1900 from the date input vba

Tags: vba, date, sum

I am trying to keep the date of some event occurrence. I am having trouble with the way my data has been defined. Instead of showing the actual date the output is showing in 1900 format (like 10/1/1900)

Here is my code:

```
Dim Arr_rate As Date
Dim D(528) As Date
for i = 3 to 500
Arr_rate = -3.7 * Log(Rnd) '<~~ Arrival interval
D(2) = CDate(1 / 1 / 2006)
D(i) = D(i - 1) + Arr_rate
Worksheets("A").Cells(i, "E").Value = Cdate(D(i)) 

next i
```

I tried to have the sdate format in my code but it will not give me the numbers in a proper format (1/1/2006). How can I print in the proper format? I have read some post in stackover flow but was not helpful!

Comment: or just `D(2) = #1/1/2006#`

Comment: It says: "compile error! expected expression."

Comment: @Zapata Don't keep on adding problems in the existing question by editing it. If your original question is answered mark it as answer and yes upvote it too, Somebody spent some time on that. Got a new question? Ask it separately.  Read this:http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/ pretty soon people will start avoiding your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without quotes `1\1\12006` is just a mathematical expression and not a date.

```
Sub test()

    Dim Arr_rate As Date
    Dim D(528) As Date
    For i = 3 To 500
        Arr_rate = -3.7 * Log(Rnd) '<~~ Arrival interval
        '<~~ Using Cdate, then use string. Otherwise 1 / 1 / 2006 evaluates to 4.98504486540379E-04
        D(2) = CDate("1 / 1 / 2006")
        D(i) = D(i - 1) + Arr_rate
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "E").Value = CDate(D(i))
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: The code works when I check the code and move the cursor on variables. But it does not print anything. Did it print the dates for you?

Comment: If you have sheet named Sheet1, check column E of that sheet. :)

Comment: the code works well till the if code come and wants to repeat one row. After that the formatting goes wring again (1900).

Comment: The arr_rate makes everything wrong when IF statement comes true!

Comment: Don't keep on adding problems in the existing question by editing it. If your original question is answered mark it as answer and yes upvote it too, Somebody spent some time on that. Got a new question? Ask it separately.  Read this:http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/ pretty soon people will start avoiding your questions.